# Can a particle accelerator save our climate?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, particle-physics, climate-science, particle-accelerators

A particle accelerator needs lots of energy to produce antimatter like positrons. But can energy consumed for the particle accelerator be "recycled"? Conversion of mass in energy has the highest energy value per mass. 
We produce lots of waste, we can recycle material or burn the waste. But burning the waste would lead to an amount of energy that is by far not as high as colliding the waste with antimatter. Would it be possible that energy consumed for particle accelerator experiments can be regained after colliding antimatter with waste?

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer here is NO. Definitely not.

It is true that a particle accelerator produces antimatter, but the energy needed to create the antimatter has to come from somewhere (large amounts of electricity), and there are inevitably losses in in the process.

Also then you annihilate your "waste" the full amount of energy will not be extractable as useful work.

So at best, your "accelerator recycling plant" is just a very inefficient furnace.

Answer (score 0):

The energy in the LHC after an experiment is dumped into a large graphite "dump block", it's the equivalent of what would be needed to melt a ton of copper. This 10 ton block of graphite is encased in about 1000 tons of steel and concrete and cooled down from a high of 800 degrees Celsius.

[image]

Image Source: [LHC Dump Block](https://www.lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.lhc_layout)